# Single line Output for the Factorial of a given number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input("Enter the Value for n:"))
result=1
for i in range(n, 1, -1):
    result=result*i
    print("factorial of",n,"is",result)
```

output comes like this:

```
Enter the Value for n:4
factorial of 4 is 4
factorial of 4 is 12
factorial of 4 is 24
```

My ask is - how to get the output only in single line i.e. the last line?

Comment: Move the print out of the loop.

Comment: If you're printing every time the result is multiplying, how did you expect only one printed result?

Answer (score 0):

printing in one line in python goes like:

```
print('hello', end='')
print(' world')
```

the output is :hello world

hopefully, that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

bring the print command out of the loop and print you result only once

```
n=int(input("Enter the Value for n:"))
result=1
for i in range(n, 1, -1):
    result=result*i
print("factorial of",n,"is",result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get particularly fancy about it, you can compute the factorial manually, build the intermediate print values as a string, and print it all in only 1 line of code (excluding an import).

The following prints a tuple where the first element is the computed factorial, and the second is a string (printed on one line) of intermediate information.

```
from functools import reduce
n=4

print(reduce(lambda x,y:(x[0]*y,"%s more text %d"%(x[1],x[0])),range(n,1,-1),(1,"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
import math
num = int(input('Enter the number:')
f = math.factorial(num)
print('The factorial of {} is {}'.format(num, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce and lambda function

```
>>> z =5
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,range(1,z+1))
120
```

This might be helpful